# Regex grammar parser end of string error

Tags: regex, parsing, grammar

I'm writing a grammar to compile .abc files. These are text files where each line of text is a music voice (an instrument playing some notes). In my grammar I take advantage of the line-by-line structure of the text to parse one line at the time. A simplified grammar looks like this.

```
// Body

// spaces and tabs have explicit meaning in the body, don't automatically ignore them

abc_body ::= abc_line+;
abc_line ::= element+ end_of_line (lyric end_of_line)?  | middle_of_body_field | comment;
element ::= note_element | rest_element | tuplet_element | barline | nth_repeat | space_or_tab; 

// notes
note_element ::= note | chord;

note ::= pitch note_length?;
pitch ::= accidental? basenote octave?;
octave ::= "'"+ | ","+;
note_length ::= (digit+)? ("/" (digit+)?)?;
note_length_strict ::= digit+ "/" digit+;

// "^" is sharp, "_" is flat, and "=" is neutral
accidental ::= "^" | "^^" | "_" | "__" | "=";

basenote ::= "C" | "D" | "E" | "F" | "G" | "A" | "B" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "f" | "g" | "a" | "b";

// rests
rest_element ::= "z" note_length?;

// tuplets
tuplet_element ::= tuplet_spec note_element+;
tuplet_spec ::= "(" digit ;

// chords
chord ::= "[" note+ "]";

barline ::= "|" | "||" | "[|" | "|]" | ":|" | "|:";
nth_repeat ::= "[1" | "[2";

// A voice field might reappear in the middle of a piece
// to indicate the change of a voice
middle_of_body_field ::= field_voice;

lyric ::= "w:" lyrical_element*;
lyrical_element ::= " "+ | "-" | "_" | "*" | "~" | backslash_hyphen | "|" | lyric_text;
// lyric_text should be defined appropriately
lyric_text ::= [.]*;

backslash_hyphen ::= "\\" "-";
//backslash immediately followed by hyphen

// General

comment ::= space_or_tab* "%" comment_text newline;
//comment_text should be defined appropriately
comment_text ::= [.]*;

end_of_line ::= newline | comment;

digit ::= [0-9];
newline ::= "\n" | "\r" "\n"?;
space_or_tab ::= " " | "\t";

text ::= .*;
```

But I have a problem with this approach. For any valid .abc file, I get an error for the last line of the file. The parser tries to match to an end_of_line but encounters an end of string. That would mean there is is a needs to be new line after the last time. Any suggestions or work around this problem?

Comment: Text files always end with a newline character (at least, that's the what the standards require), so this shouldn't really be a problem in theory. In practice, sometimes the last line of a file doesn't have a trailing newline, but since text editors don't make it easy to create such a file, they're pretty rare in practice. Does the problem actually occur when you are parsing a single-line test string from a string literal?

Comment: @rici So this grammar is overly simplified. There is a header parser that is not giving any problems, but the body parser does. If I give a body of just a single empty line I still get the same error.

Comment: Your grammar doesn't accept new lines, and as I understand abc format, empty lines are tune separators so they cannot appear in a body. Anyway, I think you need to provide a clearer problem descriptor with a real (possibly simplified) grammar.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to refactor the grammar (i.e., with no change to the language), to factor the final `newline` out of `abc_line`, i.e. to the point that you can write

`abc_line ::= abc_line_content newline`

Then, change:

`abc_body ::= abc_line+`

to:

`abc_body ::= abc_line_content (newline abc_line_content)*`

(appending `newline?` if necessary, i.e. if some files *do* have a newline at the end of the last line).